# Using CC BY-SA 4.0 data file for calculations on rest server used by closed source game

Tags: copyright, cc-by-sa

I'm making word game which is based on semantic similarity between words.

For that i need word vectors file. One of such file is available here, licensed under CC BY-SA 4.0:
https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet-numberbatch

That file will be used by simple rest server written in Python. That server will use Gensim Python package which allows reading such files and use them for calculations. Those files can come from many sources, as they share same format.

That server would provide one method - calculating similarity (as number) between two words.

My game will call that server method. So in my game I won't use that file directly nor will I distribute it. My game will just use calculated similarity from rest server.

I'm confused about how ShareAlike applies to my case.

- Do I need to release my game code under CC BY-SA 4.0 license?
- Do I need to release my server code under CC BY-SA 4.0 license?

Answer (score 3):

The principles mentioned in the [GPL FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLOutput) work in both ways:

- The license of software does not create any implications on the license of the data processed by the software
- The license of data does not have any implications on the license of the software processing the data.

Do I need to release my game code under CC BY-SA 4.0 license? **No**

Do I need to release my server code under CC BY-SA 4.0 license? **No**